# Using mysql to query a table with a product code which is part of a filename

Tags: php

I am trying to query a table which has a column called "filename".

The actual filename is made up of "productcode-category.jpg"

If i have the product code posted to a php page, how could i then take the value and search in the filename column where it equals the product code?

It would be great if it wasnt case sensitive as well.

Comment: "Posted to" how? Through a form? As a variable?

Comment: yep, i was just thinking actually i could use LIKE% ?

Comment: create the table collate such as latin1_general_ci or utf8_general_ci to allow case insensitive, other part of the question is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql searches are case insensitive by default. You have to specifically request case sensitivty by doing `SELECT ... WHERE BINARY somefield = 'CaseSEnSITive'`. As for searching as you want, you could do:

SELECT blah, blah
  FROM table
  WHERE filename LIKE '%product_code_here%'

But this could produce many false positives if your product codes are variable length (e.g. a product has code '1' and many others have code '11', '12', '13', etc...). You would save yourself hassle if you created a seperate product code field and could do direct comparisons on that, rather than a substring match as the 'LIKE' comparison does.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the product code defined in the same table as the one which has the "filename" column ? Can you show us your tables ?

Case sensitivity is most probably defined in your database. (see your charset : ex latin1_swedish_ci : the 'ci' means case insensitive). This is the default value, you may want to override this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your table structure may be a little less than efficient if you want to do product code lookups by parsing a filename.  However, you probably want a query something like this:

```
SELECT filename FROM mytable WHERE filename LIKE 'somestring-%';
```

If you stored your product codes and categories in separate columns, the query could be much faster:

```
SELECT filename FROM mytable WHERE product_code = 'somestring';
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Thats what i've rolled with

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE STRTOUPPER(filename) LIKE "'.STRTOUPPER($productcode).'%";
```